# Lagrange's Lemma in number theory

Tags: number-theory

On proof of Lagrange's Lemma, I read this: << Write  $p=4m+1$ . By Wilson's Theorem, and  $2m+i\equiv-(2m-i+1)\,mod\,p$ ,

$(4m)!\equiv(2m)!^2\equiv-1\,mod\,p$ .. >>

I don't understand this last equation.

And finally follows: << Putting  $n=(2m)!$  we habe  $n^2+1\equiv0\,mod\,p$

Therefore: If $p\equiv1\,mod\,4$  is prime, then  $p\mid n^2+1$  for some integer  $n$ >>

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $p=4m+1$ then $p-1=4m$ and $(p-1)!\equiv-1\mod p $ by Wilson's theorem

Comment: and $(4m)!=1\times2\times...\times 2m\times(2m+1)\times (2m+2)...\times 4m$ $=[1\times2\times...\times 2m]\times (p-2m)\times(p-(2m-1))\times...\times(p-1)\equiv(2m)!(2m)!=(2m)!^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p=4m+1,$ then $p-1=4m,$

and $(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p$ by Wilson's theorem, so we have $(4m)!\equiv-1\pmod p$.

Also $(4m)!=1\times2\times...\times 2m\times(2m+1)\times (2m+2)\times...\times 4m$

$=[1\times2\times...\times 2m]\times (p-2m)\times(p-(2m-1))\times...\times(p-1)$

$\equiv_p[1\times2\times...\times2m]\times(-1)^{2m}\times(2m)\times(2m-1)\times...\times1\equiv_p(2m)!(2m)!=(2m)!^2.$

This explains the equation you did not understand;

let me know if you have further questions about this.

Comment: Great explanation. But it's a little hard for me this:  $(p-2m)x(p-(2m-1))x...x(p-1)\,=\,(-1)^{2m}x(2m)x(2m-1)x...x1$ Thank you

Comment: $\mod p:  p-2m\equiv-2m, p-(2m-1)\equiv-(2m-1), ... p-1\equiv -1$ so their product  $\equiv(-2m)(-(2m-1))...(-1)\equiv(-1)(2m)(-1)(2m-1)...(-1)\equiv(-1)^{2m}(2m)(2m-1)...1$

Comment: $mod\,p$ !  Ok. Now yes